# Finding all two words and bolding them all using vba in Word 2016

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a requirements document RD that contains "must" and "shall" in Word 2016 that I'm trying to find all occurences and bold the words. I'm using the example Microsoft provided on their website for the Object model for "how to find and replace text" at this weblink https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/finding-and-replacing-text-or-formatting

I've changed the word "blue" to "must" and added a second search too for "shall" and performed an execute on each within the same with. It only finds the first one of each and stops even when I set wdFindContinue.  In the code below, I've commented out the second search as I tried to find out why it won't find all of them in the document.

Here's the test sentences in word I'm using to run the VBA code on.

> The RD shall follow template standards.

> The RD shall be written using the word must.
> The RD must be checked to comply with template standards. The RD will be signed-off by the group manager.

Here's the VBA code I'm using based on Microsofts example. The commented code at the end is from microsoft too for use possibly in the future so it can be ignored.

```
Public Sub BoldMustShall()

' This searches the RD document for must and shall
' and changes them to bold.

With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
  '.ClearFormatting
  .Forward = True
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
   
 '.Text = "must"
 .Execute FindText:="must"
 If .Found = True Then
 .Parent.Bold = True
 Debug.Print "Found must "
 End If
 
 ' .Text = "shall"
 '.Execute FindText:="shall"
 'If .Found = True Then
 '.Parent.Bold = True
 'Debug.Print "Found shall "
 'End If
End With

' The code having problems is above here.

' Alternate method of doing the same thing for must/shall
' Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
' myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="must", Forward:=True
' If myRange.Find.Found = True Then myRange.Bold = True

 ' A method that will replace all the "shalls" with "must" and then apply above to bold it.
 'With Selection.Find
 '.ClearFormatting
 '.Text = "shall"
 '.Replacement.ClearFormatting
 '.Replacement.Text = "must"
 '.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
 'Wrap:=wdFindContinue
 ' End With
 
 ' A method to find all bolded text and unbold it.
 'With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
 '.ClearFormatting
 '.Font.Bold = True
 'With .Replacement
 '.ClearFormatting
 '.Font.Bold = False
 'End With
 '.Execute FindText:="", ReplaceWith:="", _
 'Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 'End With
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "shall"
    .Replacement.Text = "shall"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchControl = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "must"
    .Replacement.Text = "must"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchControl = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

I simply recorded a macro replacing `shall` with `shall` bolded. Then duplicated it for `must`.

You need to set the same text for find and replace. A shortcut is to use `^&` as the replace which means the find text. EG `BB^&` when searching for *must* will change to *BBmust*.

Comment: This gives me an idea of the recording macro's capability although I haven't used it.  There is a missing statement to turn the text bold once found.  I added it from the other answer posted and this routine works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Text = "must"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "shall"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer works. I had trouble finding what the ^& did, but found that it eliminates the need for more than one statement for the text to search for. This is pretty nifty. I also wanted to narrow down the search to only text that is normal style and ignore figure/table captions and headings that have these words. I modified my test statements to test the modifications. The changes are,.

Replacement.Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 20
    .Replacement.Font.Italic = True
    .Style = wdStyleNormal

Comment: One of the issues is I have a user-defined style Appendix 1-9 based on Heading1-9. When wdHeading1 is specified it can find it and change the words in Heading1; however, I don't know how to search for the words in the user-defined Appendix1 style  since it ignores the words in this style. This is for the previous comment.

Comment: I found that when the replacement text isn't specified and the execute specifies wdreplaceall, that the text searched for is replaced with null.  Moreover. if the .parent.font.bold=true is specified, it will also change all the text within the document bold and not just what is searched for. It's unknown if this is a bug due to the null since it can't figure out what text to bold. If the wdreplacall isn't specified, then it will bold the first occurence it finds for each word from the beginning of the range regardless if the wdFindContinue and Wrap=true. The same applies for  wdFindask nopopup

Comment: Kindly post each question in its own separate thread, not in comments unrelated to the original question in this thread. The '.Parent' behaviour is to be expected, since the '.Parent' of any found range is the document as a whole.